# Passing Values to Query String

Tags: c#

I am working on a survey application its console app which get users information from database and send them SMS on their number to start a survey SMS contains a gizmo survey link . Company also wants to track some user information loyalityCardNumber , shopId, receiptNumer . I created a string now i am trying to getValue from database but link is not showing me correct values which i am expecting . 
I am passing two parameters , phone number and other parameters . 
Please see this code sample

```
public const string RetailSms = "Thank for purchasing our app please dedicate some time about your purchase experience. http://www.surveygizmo.com/?{Fidelity}=fidelity&{Csstor}=csstor";
 var URL = "3456299220", Constants.RetailSms.("fidelity", receptient.fidelity).Replace("csstor", Convert.ToString(receptient.csstor));
```

Comment: This certainly is not C.

Comment: yes indeed my mistake its c#

Comment: Your string is called `RetailSms` but you don't appear to be using that in the second line? It might help to debug what the replace is creating and give us some more information

Comment: now i edited my string its URL .

Comment: I don't even want to try if your second line of code is accepted by the compiler. Please separate your concerns (1) get values from database (2) construct an URL string from values. Do not try to do both things in a single step and if you have problems with both, ask two separate questions please.

Comment: Now its URL a variable where i am storing values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue with following code .

public const string RetailSms = "Thank for purchasing our app please dedicate some time about your purchase experience. http://www.surveygizmo.com/&{Fidelity}=fidelity&{Csstor}=csstor";

```
  var URL = Constants.CornerSms.Replace("{fidelity}", receptient.fidelity)
                        .Replace("{csstor}", receptient.csstor.ToString())
```